# how to paste n times the same column?

Tags: bash, paste

I have two files with different length, e.g. file1 reads

```
A    
B    
C    
D    
E
```

and file2

```
1
```

I am looking for a way to create file3 like:

```
A  1
B  1
C  1
D  1
E  1
```

I know that if file1 and file2 had the same length a simple `paste file1 file2 > file3` would solve the problem.

Comment: does file2 always have just one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### take 1

If file2 only has one line, I would do

```
awk -v f2="$(< file2)" '{print $0, f2}' file1
```

if file contains, say, 3 lines and you want the output to look like:

```
a 1
b 2
c 3
d 1
e 2
```

then I would do

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {f2[FNR]=$0; n=FNR; next}
    {print $0, f2[((FNR-1)%n)+1]}
' file2 file1
```

### take 2

Here's a crazy way to use paste and a process substitution that repeats file2 so that it's the same length as file1

```
printf "%s\n" {A..Z} >|file1
seq 1 3 >| file2

paste file1 <(
    lf1=$(wc -l < file1)
    lf2=$(wc -l < file2)
    for (( i=0; i <= lf1/lf2; i++)); do
      cat file2
    done | head -n $lf1
)
```

```
A   1
B   2
C   3
D   1
E   2
F   3
G   1
H   2
I   3
J   1
K   2
L   3
M   1
N   2
O   3
P   1
Q   2
R   3
S   1
T   2
U   3
V   1
W   2
X   3
Y   1
Z   2
```

Answer (score 1):

One way with `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next}{x=a[FNR]?a[FNR]:x;$2=x}1' file2 file1 > file3
```